# How to sort an an array having mulitple time slots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array `collected_slots = ["09:30", "09:45", "09:40", "09:55", "09:35", "09:50"]`

I have to sort it on the bases of the time, I have tried

```
sorted_slots = collected_slots.sort_by do |slot|
parsed = collected_slots[:time].split('-').first
[parsed&.to_i, parsed.split(':').second&.to_i]
```

but it doesn't work

What I want is `collected_slots = ["09:30-09:35", "09:35-09:40", "09:40-09:45", "09:45-09:50", "09:50-09:55"]`

I have tried but it doesn't works. Please help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried `collected_slots.sort #=> ["09:30", "09:35", "09:40", "09:45", "09:50", "09:55"]`? See [String#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), which is used by [Array#sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) for ordering strings.

Comment: Does the array always have an even number of elements?

Comment: I think this a simple typo. You need to use the `slot` variable in your block. It looks like you're accessing some unrelated object instead...

Comment: @max, I'm confused. Can we call you "little max", as opposed to "big Max"?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want.

1. Sort the entries after converting each entry to a DateTime object.
2. map the index, except the last index, of each entry to the value at that index and the value at the next index

```rb
require 'date'
input = ["09:30", "09:45", "09:40", "09:55", "09:35", "09:50"]
sorted = input.sort_by {DateTime.parse(_1)}
output = sorted[0...-1].each_index.map {"#{sorted[_1]}-#{sorted[_1+1]}"}
```

```
=> ["09:30-09:35", "09:35-09:40", "09:40-09:45", "09:45-09:50", "09:50-09:55"]
```